# Issue in Regex expression for multiline string - Uipath

Tags: regex, uipath

I want to replace a word love with hates in a multi line,
The regex that I use:

```
(?<=>.*)(?<!\w)loves(?!\w)(?=.*<)
```

Input samples:

```
<p>hello i am human,
loves dogs.
</p>  - highlights loves in 2nd line
<p>hello i am human,
loves dogs.</p>  - highlights loves in 2nd line
<h1>loves dsdfsf</h1> -highlight loves
<h2>fdsfsd loves </h1> -highlight loves
<h3>dloves</h3> - ignore
<li> loves</li> -highlight loves
<li>loves </li> -highlight loves
<variable>lovesd</variable> - ignore lovesd
<h2 class="loves">loves</h2>  - ignore the loves in within <h2 class="loves">,
```

`(?<=>.*)(?<!\w)loves(?!\w)(?=.*<)`

This regex works for single line, but doesn't work for multiline

Comment: Add `(?s)` dot all modifier. Does this regex run under C# or ECMA 2023 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the dot-all modifier `s` if you keep the `.*` form.

However that form will also match inside tags.
To keep the match between tags use `[^>]` and `[^<]` respectively.

```
/(?<=>[^<]*)(?<!\w)loves(?!\w)(?=[^>]*<)/gs
```

https://regex101.com/r/7CaGMU/1

Note that if you do not use the dot, then the dot-all modifier is irrelevant.
Even that is not the best way to parse this anyway. , but it's better than before.

```
(?<= > [^<]* )
(?<! \w )
loves
(?! \w )
(?= [^>]* < )
```